# ¿Cómo insertar datos en MySQL? C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Tengo un programa que recibe datos cada X tiempo, lo que quiero es que esos datos vayan a una base de datos ejecutando querys cada vez que se cumplan algunas opciones.

La BBDD está en otro equipo, dentro de la red interna, por lo que localhost no me vale.

¿Hay alguna manera de conectarme por la url? Y sino, ¿Como puedo hacerlo a través de la ip?

En realidad, me vale cualquier manera para poder establecer conexión con la ip y mandar sentencias SQL del tipo `INSERT`

Estaba intentando esto, pero no tiene que ver con SQL, aún así, lo dejo por si sirve de algo.

```
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source = nombreServidor, Puerto;"+
        "Network Library = DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog = dashboard;"+
        "User ID = XXXX; Password = XXXXX");


        try { 
        sql.Open();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        //declaramos la variable para comandos
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();`
```

Comment: La ip usuario y pasword no tenían nada que ver con las reales, pero aún así, la edición está aprobada, gracias.

Comment: Hay algo raro en tu consulta. Si te estas conectando mediante `phpMyAdmin`,estas seguro de que la base de datos es sql server y no mySql?

Comment: Tienes razón es MySQl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando un conector que es para Sql Server y estás intentando conectarte a un servidor MySql. Para conectarte a MySql desde .Net necesitas instalar un conector específico, [MySql .Net Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) y usar las clases específicas, como MySqlConnection o MySqlCommand.

Ejemplo de uso (tomado de [la documentación de MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html)):

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
"pwd=12345;database=test";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Me podrías añadir un ejemplo sencillo de conexión a ip y lanzar una consulta, cualquier cosa sencilla para basarme en algo, nunca he tratado con bases de datos en C#, tan solo con ficheros de texto.

Comment: @AritzBello acabo de ponerte un ejemplo,pero en la documentación del enlace que te he pasado tienes todo.

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que buscaba.